# How to play audio from buffer in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, audiobuffer

I am trying to play audio from buffer which is streamed from android to android.
Tried using AudioTrack which works for PCM format only.To play MP3, I am looking to use MediaPlayer but it doesn't support playing from buffer.How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a few options...
1) (Probably bad option) You can actually make what you ask work by using a local proxy to feed `MediaPlayer` the MP3 data. This is not very straightforward, but I am sure it can work.
2) Decode the MP3 data and use `AudioTrack`. This is the more lightweight option if you are willing to use a 3rd party library for decoding. See [this link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/). There are probably other libraries that can be used for decoding.

UPDATE:
Unfortunately, the link I provided is now broken. My apologies for not capturing more information in the answer. As the OP says in the comment, decode using [`MediaCodec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) and play back using [`AudioTrack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have a doubt, Is it possible to decode a buffer and play it using audiotrack? because I am not gonna use any file to save the data I receiving.
my current scenario for example
while(1) {
 receive_audio_data(buf); /* receives audio data of 4kb*/
 decode_received_data(buf); /* decoding 4kb mp3 audio data */
 audioTrack.write(buf, 0, 4096);
}
will it work?

Comment: You should not need it to be put in a file. It should work keeping the data in memory.

Comment: Decoded MP3 using MediaoCodec and played it using AudioTrack.